# What are the syntaxes for pathnames under Windows and under Linux respectively?

Tags: linux, windows, path

i am considering to write a program to check if a pathname is valid.

1. What is the syntax of pathnames (including relative ones) under Windows? I googled it a while, and I only found error report about individual cases for invalid pathnames.
2. Same question for Linux? Although I used Linux most of time, I don't know if there is a standard document that defines it. POSIX?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Windows has multiple layers (NT, Win32, Posix/WSL) and multiple path types but you are probably referring to the DOS/Win32 type and that subject is complicated enough on its own.

You have the basic DOS paths:

- Absolute: `d:\dir\subdir\file`
- Current directory relative: `file`, `.\subdir\file` and `..\otherfile`
- Root relative/current drive: `\dir\subdir\file`
- Drive relative: `d:file`
- "Upstream": `d:\dir\..\otherdir\file` etc.
- UNC: `\\server\share\file`
- Drive/volume: `d:`

There are also special reserved names like `NUL`, `CON`, `AUX` and `COM1`.

Windows NT added further complications:

- Named streams: `d:\dir\subdir\file:stream`
- Escaped/long path: `\\?\d:\file`
- Escaped UNC: `\\?\UNC\server\share\file`
- Device paths: `\\.\PhysicalDisk1`
- [Volume GUID path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365248(v=vs.85).aspx): `\\?\Volume{26a21bda-a627-11d7-9931-806e6f6e6963}\`

If you are operating at the higher shell level you also have a couple additional types to deal with:

- shell protocol: `shell:SendTo`
- Shell namespace: `::{someGUID}\::{anotherGUID}`

Most functions will also accept `/` as a path separator. Even something as crazy as `d:f:s` (stream s in file f relative to current directory on drive d) should be considered valid.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx) for more information.

Linux on the other hand only treats `/` and a null byte (`\0`) as special and will allow you to use newline characters etc. in a path. IFS can often be used if you are dealing with paths in a shell script. Read [this rant for more information](https://www.dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html).